# How to use xcopy with /exclude in a network path with spaces?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, batch, xcopy

I want to use `xcopy` on a network path. I actually do.

The problem is that I wanted to use an `/exclude` option. But the file would be in a network path. But the network path has spaces (`s:\my path`).

So this is what I'm using and **it's working** right now **without** `/exclude` (`S:` is a mapped network file):

```
xcopy "S:\TI\My Path" "C:\Path" /S /I /D /Q /Y
```

I've tried adding an `/exclude` file **locally** and **it works** fine (figured out I must use the 8.3 name):

```
xcopy "S:\TI\My Path" "C:\Path" /S /I /D /Q /Y /exclude:c:\MyConf~1\cfg.txt
```

But the same didn't work when I move to a network path. I think the main reason is that network path doesn't have a 8.3 name according to  `dir /x`.

```
xcopy "S:\TI\My Path" "C:\Path" /S /I /D /Q /Y /exclude:s:\MyConf~1\cfg.txt
```

> Impossible to read the file: s:\MyConf~1\cfg.txt

*The line above was translated by me from Brazilian Portuguese and may not be exactly what `xcopy` returns. But I think you get it.*

I've tried to use a not mapped version, which is not practical actually and didn't work.

```
xcopy "S:\TI\My Path" "C:\Path" /S /I /D /Q /Y /exclude:\\server\MyConf~1\cfg.txt
```

Is there a way I can achieve this with `xcopy`? Is there any equivalent who does not need an install in every PC?

Comment: I think you must find a way to not use 8.3

Comment: @S.Brottes I've tried. It refuses to find the file. It parses partially when it finds a space.

Comment: Have you try to put the full path with quotes / double quotes ?

Comment: Why do you insist on using an 8.3 name over the network? Using the full folder name should work.

Comment: @S.Brottes with double quotes or singles quotes it says the same: Impossible to read the file "s:\My configs\cfg.txt". As far as I cant tell the exclude option does not support quotes.

Comment: @harrymc I've tried it first. It does not work using the full folder name. With quotes it says that can't read the file `'s:\My configs\cfg.txt'`, without quotes it  says that can't read the file `s:\my` and breaks in the space.

Comment: Can you try by removing the space in your path to check if it works ?

Comment: @S.Brottes it actually works. But the example above has a much simpler path than the one I actually must use. I couldn't use a path without spaces. It would work if the batch maps the long network path `S:\TI\My Configs` to `T:\` but in this case the batch would need the not mapped version of the path hard coded, which is not what we need.  It would work as workaround though.

Comment: Seems like you're missing quotes around the full file-name.

Comment: @harrymc Sorry. I think my previous answer to you were not clear. I've tried with two kinds of quotes in the exclude:  `xcopy "S:\TI\My Path" "C:\Path" /S /I /D /Q /Y /exclude:"s:\My Configs\cfg.txt"` and `xcopy "S:\TI\My Path" "C:\Path" /S /I /D /Q /Y /exclude:'s:\My Configs\cfg.txt'`. Both did not work. It says it can't read the file and mention it with the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a not so elegant solution with help of an idea the user [S. Brottes](https://superuser.com/users/964984/s-brottes) gave me in the [comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1736670/how-to-use-xcopy-with-exclude-in-a-network-path-with-spaces?noredirect=1#comment2689017_1736670).

I found a code to see the full UNC path associated with the letter [here](https://www.thecodeteacher.com/question/34902/windows---Find-UNC-path-of-a-network-drive?) and made some changes.

My code finds the full UNC path of the letter I've already had mapped (in this case `s:`) gets the full UNC path and concatenates.

After that I map it to an unused letter and use it in the `exclude` parameter:

```
@REM Get the full UNC path, maps it to a letter, use the letter in the exclude parameter and exludes the mapped letter
cls

@set _NetworkPath=
@set _newLetterDrive=y

@REM finds the complete network path mapped to s:
@pushd "s:"

@for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic path win32_mappedlogicaldisk get deviceid^, providername ^| findstr /i "%CD:~0,2%"') do @(set _NetworkPath=%%i%CD:~2%)

@REM concatenates the actual network path with the added folder I need
@REM @echo. Debug info %_NetworkPath%

@set _newPath="%_NetworkPath%TI\My configs"

@REM maps deep into the folder to a known not used letter
net use %_newLetterDrive%: %_newPath%

@REM finally call the xcopy with the exclude file pointed out directly by y:
@REM @echo Debug info %_newPath%

xcopy "S:\TI\My Path" "C:\Path" /S /I /D /Q /Y /exclude:%_newLetterDrive%:\cfg.txt


@REM removes the used letter
net use %_newLetterDrive%: /delete /yes
```